# Warning: stripos() expects at least 2 parameters in php

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I wrote a simple function in php and passing arguments to uppercase the letters based on passing array index value but I'm getting this error

> Warning: stripos() expects at least 2 parameters

what I'm doing wrong can anyone suggest me.

i'm newbie to php just starts learning.

```
<?php
 function doCapital($string, $array)
 {
     $stringArray = explode(",", $string); 

     for( $i=0; $i<count($stringArray); $i++)
     {
         if(stripos($stringArray)>-1){
             $stringArray[$i] = $stringArray[$i].ucfirst();
             echo $stringArray[$i];
         }
     }

     return implode(" ",$stringArray);
 }

 echo doCapital('abcd', [1,2]);
```

Comment: Did you know about [`ucwords()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, on re-reading my last answer I realise that it did seem very unfriendly - I bashed out a quick answer and didn't read it back.  What I was trying to say is that with errors like this the quickest solutions to go to the php manual and check the required parameters - which in this case is a needle and a haystack (i.e something to search, and something to search in).

You will likely find the same error here 
`$stringArray[$i] = $stringArray[$i].ucfirst();` as ucfirst requires a string to be passed - here you're using it like jQuery so php thinks you are trying to concatenate a string, it should say `ucfirst($stringArray[$i])`

you also can't explode with a comma unless your string contains them, so in the example you have you would receive the same string back, I think you mean to use something like `str_split`

also I would reiterate that I think you need to use `in_array` for what you're trying to achieve, like this:

```
function doCapital($string, $array)
{
    $stringArray = str_split($string); 

    foreach($stringArray as $key => $value)
    {
        //see if the key exists in the array of characters to change the case for 
        //and update if it does
        if(in_array($key,$array)){
            $stringArray[$key] = ucfirst($value);//thinking about it I might just use strtoupper since there's only one letter anyway - I'm not sure that there's any real performance benefit either way
        }
    }
    return implode("",$stringArray);
 }

 echo doCapital('abcd', [1,2]); //outputs aBCd
```

Comment: this is what I'm trying to do. thanks for giving clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> **[stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) - Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string**

You are missing the second parameter, The correct syntax to use the function `stripos` is

```
stripos ($haystack ,$needle);
```

Here

`$haystack` -> *The string in which you are searching*

`$needle`  -> *The substring*

For example :

```
$findme    = 'x';
$mystring1 = 'xyz';
$pos1 = stripos($mystring1, $findme);
if ($pos1 !== false) {
   echo "We found '$findme' in '$mystring1' at position $pos1";
}
```

Comment: i have done same program in js. but in php getting this error check my codepen link https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/yrdLrW so you can understand what i'm trying to say.

Comment: @Husna JS !== PHP in the slightest - just read the docs and things become self-explanatory :)